# MySQL Tuning & Performance via Query_Cache

Tags: mysql, performance

I am experiencing slow performance with a CMS (WordPress) on my server.

I ran `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';`

Result:

```
Variable_name               Value
Qcache_free_blocks          0
Qcache_free_memory          0
Qcache_hits                 0
Qcache_inserts              0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes        0
Qcache_not_cached           0
Qcache_queries_in_cache     0
Qcache_total_blocks         0
```

I am thinking that values of zero are not good. Does anyone know if these values are okay? If they are not, do you have any recommendations on how I can improve my sites performance relative to MySQL?

Thanks.

**AMENDED**

Prior to running the command above, I ran `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';`.

Result:

```
Variable_name       Value
have_query_cache    YES
```

**AMENDMENT #2**

Then I ran `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%';`

Result:

```
Variable_name                   Value
query_cache_limit               1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit        4096
query_cache_size                0
query_cache_type                ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
```

**AMENDMENT #3**

Then I ran `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_slow_queries';`

Result:

```
Variable_name       Value
log_slow_queries    OFF
```

Comment: Looks like query cache is not on. Can you run this. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';`

Comment: Oh, sorry @ MikeBrant. See my amended question.

Comment: @Dr.Tot But what did you get when you run the statement I mentioned?  If you get a value of `YES` then the cache is enabled and there is some other problem, otherwise the cache is not enabled (which is likely here).

Comment: see my amendment @MikeBrant (you're a bit to quick for my typing :)

Comment: OK runs `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%'` a let us know what you get.

Comment: Sorry I also should have asked you to run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_slow_queries'` to determine if slow query logging is on.  This is unrelated to query cache but could be useful in diagnosing problematic queries.

Comment: What version of MySQL? Are you only using prepared statements for your queries?

Comment: We are running 5.0.51a. And I am not sure what "prepared statements for your queries" actually means. Sorry @MikeBrant

Comment: Amended again @MikeBrant

Comment: If the application is using prepared statements to execute it queries (as many developers are fond of using these days), you will never see any benefit of the query cache on the old version of MySQL, as it will not use the query cache for prepared statements. I think the best place to start would be to turn on slow query logs so you can begin to determine the queries which are the worst performance offenders. Check out this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: Oh, I got it -- I think "prepared statements" is the same as what I know them to be which is "stored procedures". Anyway, my CMS is WordPress if that sheds light in anyway. I'll turn on slow query logging and follow your link. Thanks @MikeBrant.

Comment: Prepared statements are not the same a stored procedures. I believe more recent versions of Wordpress do make extensive use of prepared statements (not sure if everything is prepared statements).  You may want to consider upgrading your MySQL version to 5.1.21 or higher (ideally 5.5) if you are able, in order to take advantage of query caching. In the meantime, you can still use slow query logs to look for especially bad queries.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately, my WP app is not the only thing running on the server. Upgrading MySQL would be a much larger project than what I am trying to accomplish given the magnitude of mission critical apps running in our PROD environment. So I'll need to watch the slow logs and find other ways to optimize WP. Appreciate your help on this @MikeBrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values show that the query cache is not active. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html